# Output data from MS SQL Database inside a table structure using a while loop

Tags: php, sql-server

i have this simple code to show some data from MS SQL Database using sqlsrv :

```
    <?php
$serverName = "namesrv"; //serverName\instanceName
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"Database", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"pass");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "SELECT Code, Name FROM StoreCards";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo $row['Code'].", ".$row['Name']."<br />";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

?>
```

for test i printing data with br, but i need show this data into html table

how i can do it please?

thank you for your reply

Comment: `sqlsrv` is for MS SQL Server why is this tagged MySQL?

Comment: For each row add a `<tr>`  and for each column add a `<td>`

Comment: Make a `<table>` outside the `while` and make `<tr>`s inside, use `<td>` for each cell/data point.

Comment: Yes, working fine with thise code :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is to wrap up your code inside the HTML tag structure of a table.

```
echo "<table>";
// You can add headers to your table using <tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th></tr>
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      echo "<tr><td>".$row['Code']."</td><td>".$row['Name']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

You should take a look at this https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp to learn more about table tags

Answer (score 0):

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

$td .= '<td> '.$row['Code'].' </td> ';  
$td .= '<td> '.$row['Name'].' </td> ';
}
echo '<table><tr>' . $td . '</tr><tr>' . $td . '</tr>' . '</table>';
```

**OR**

```
echo "<table> <tr> <th> Code </th>  <th>Name</th> </tr>";

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

 echo "<tr> <td>".$row['Code']."</td> <td>".$row['Name']."</td> </tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Gonna have a lot of tables with this approach, also you don't need all those echos and you missed some quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to display each row in tr tags and content in td tags. create a table before while loop and under while loop add tr and td tags.

```
echo "<table>"; // create table
// add header if needed
echo "<tr><th>Code</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
      // display row  
      echo "<tr><td>".$row['Code']."</td><td>".$row['Name']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $sql = "SELECT Code, Name FROM StoreCards";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Code</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>";


while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```